# Can I see all attributes of a pyplot without showing the graph?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am working on developing homework as a TA for a course at my university.

We are using Otter Grader (an extension of OKPy) to grade student submissions of guided homework we provide through Jupyter Notebooks.

Students are being asked to plot horizontal lines on their plots using `matplotlib.pyplot.axhline()`, and I am hoping to use an `assert` call to determine whether they added the horizontal line to their plots.

**Is there a way to see all attributes that have been added to a pyplot in matplotlib?**

Comment: You're not going to see a specific horizontal line attribute, but you can access all the lines of the plot and see if those lines have the same y values for all points. Would you like me to show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to see if the `axhline` attribute has been used or not, but there is a way to see if the lines are horizontal by accessing all the `line2D` objects using the `lines` attribute.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def is_horizontal(line2d):
    x, y = line2d.get_data()
    y = np.array(y)  # The axhline method does not return data as a numpy array
    y_bool = y == y[0]  # Returns a boolean array of True or False if the first number equals all the other numbers
    return np.all(y_bool)


t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

plt.plot(t, t**2)
plt.plot(t, t)
plt.axhline(y=5, xmin=-10, xmax=10)

ax = plt.gca()

assert any(map(is_horizontal, ax.lines)), 'There are no horizontal lines on the plot.'

plt.show()
```

This code will raise the error if there is not at least one `line2D` object that contains data in which all the y values are the same.

Note that in order for the above to work, the `axhline` attribute has to be used instead of the `hlines` method. The `hlines` method does not add the `line2D` object to the axes object.

Comment: Thank you! The ax.lines object seems like something that I could investigate further. I take it that any of the lines in the axes object can be iterated through to find points?

Comment: Yes. Use the `get_data` method to return the two arrays. The first is the x values and the second is y values. Welcome to stack overflow! If you like an answer and think it's correct, then press that checkmark. @AlexS.

Comment: I marked your answer as the answer! Thank you for the help. I have another question if you don't mind: do you know a way to get the same data from points? If I use `plt.scatter()` or use `plt.plot()` and set linewidths to 0, the axes object no longer contains lines, meaning I cannot extract the x and y values in that way. I can ask as a separate Stack Overflow question as well.

Comment: @AlexS. You should ask another question to get more details. I'll check the questions you post later today or you can @ me on the post. If you set linewidths to 0 then it won't show up on the plot, but you should still be able to access the data from the axes object. `plt.scatter` does not return a `line2D`; instead, it returns a `PathCollection` and you would have to access it through the `collections` attribute similarly to the `lines` attribute of the axes object.